# Audio Player for MP3 Files for Wordpress

Tags: media, audio

I have a wordpress account. I am just using the free wordpress account which does not allow me to install any plugins. I have an mp3 file and I want it to appear as an audio player. There are many plugins like wpaudio but that only works if I have installed the wordpress on my server which I have not.

Comment: take a look at http://www.singingbox.org/index2.php or its alternatives

Answer (score 1):

http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/